# Android HTTP request fails

Tags: android, http

I have an app that use HTTP request to the server API.
I also have a web site that connect to the same server API.
I using google register for login in both of them.
My problem is that if no one use the web then after 24 hours or less the Android app login request fails on timeout. when I open the web the app start to work again.
In the Android app I use IP for the URL, and for the web I use domain.
I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: it looks like a server problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a web"? Is that a web site, a webview, or what? Can you provide the code?

Comment: it is surely backend related problem